# Trouble with adding image source in android studio

Tags: android

I am trying to add a source image to an ImageView in Android Studio. I placed the image in the res/drawable folder.  I have the same image placed in mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,and xxxhdpi.
However when I try to add the path to the image in xml it does not even show up.  I have attached a screenshot of what I have.
Also I tried to clean and rebuild the project and still I cannot access the images in the drawable folder.

I should add that if I try and add the images to the mipmap folders.  It works just fine and I can set the path of the images to mipmap.

[image: drawable folders in android studio]

Comment: What does the red lightbulb say?

Comment: create drawable resource file 'android.png.xml'   create drawable resource  'android.png'

Comment: You should just use `@drawable/file_name`. Get rid of the `.png`

Comment: Okay so I think I am finally getting somewhere.  It seems that when I try and create the different folders with the different size images under the drawable folder, then I can't access the images in xml.  However if I just put one single file under the main drawable folder then everything works and I am able to get to the image from xml.

Comment: Oh... I see what you did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created the extra drawables folders inside of the main drawable folder instead of using the existing folders in the `res/` directory. (See the mipmap folders?)

Also, don't need png extension in the XML, just the filename

Comment: OOOOHH....wow I see what happened.  Thanks man your a life saver, I was getting ready to pull my hair out.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Yeah, that explains why putting the files in the root of those folders worked

Answer (score 1):

In your XML remove file extension and replace `.` with `_`

```
android:src="@drawable/podcast_ac_new_2_9"
```

Comment: I tried removing the .png at the end of the line.  Still the problem persists.

Comment: I tried that and now it says " Failed to convert podcast_ac_new_2.9 into a drawable (Details)"

Comment: please check:
- all your files have name podcast_ac_new_2.9.png WITH extension
- all your files have same name
- in your XML android:src="podcast_ac_new_2_9" WITHOUT extension and dots

Comment: I checked everything.  Made sure the file names are the same and without extensions and dots.  I even went and renamed the images to a more simple name "android" just to be sure.  Still nothing seems to work.  Are issues like this typical of android development?

Comment: your file names must be WITH extension .png, but in xml it must be WHITHOUT extensions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127677/discussion-between-maxost-and-narain-ramjieawan).

Comment: You need `@drawable` still

Comment: @cricket_007 thanks, my mistake, i updated my answer