# Android studio can not detect the source file in res/drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-drawable

This is my code. I don't know how to post this image.

[image: this is my code. i don't know how to post this image]

I tried to add source file for my `ImageView`. But it doesn't work. I tried to copy the path folder and it is still not work.

Comment: Have you tried refreshing your project?

Comment: @BensonKiprono yes. But it's still the same. The first solution below worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble with adding image source in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498329/trouble-with-adding-image-source-in-android-studio)

Comment: @BensonKiprono nope. I change the resource name. It must start with a letter not a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution - first problem

The resource name must start with a letter (not number).

## Solution - second problem

Use just:

```
@drawable/039_cloud
```

instead

```
@drawable/039_cloud/039_cloud
```

so:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/039_cloud" />
```

#### Android Studio

Android Studio is grouping same images, but for different DPIs.

When you choose `Android` view, you will have:

[image]

But when you will choose `Project` you will see "real" project structure:

[image]

Comment: hi thank you for replying. I have tried that too but it's still not working

Comment: Ah i don't know how to do that sorry. I did it.

Answer (score -1):

Copy the image resource and paste it directly inside the drawable folder. Rename the image such that no number is included (e.g. image_thirty_nine.png). Then try this

```
 <ImageView
android:id="@+id/image_id"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/image_thirty_nine" />
```

If you are till getting the same error after trying the above step, then try adding the image resource programmably

```
//ensure you assignn an id to your image
   ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_id);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_thirty_nine);
```

then run your code to see if it works